# CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -15

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, cgimagesource

I'm trying to lead a TIFF image into a CGImageSource using CGImageSourceCreateWithURL. My URL is correct, is %20 encoded, is a path to an existing file, that file is a TIFF. However, the line:

```
NSString *fullPath =  [[[fileNames objectAtIndex:pageNum - 1] string]
                          stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: 
                              NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString* urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"file:/%@", fullPath];
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: fullPath];

CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL (url, NULL);
```

gives me the following error:

```
Wed Aug  4 20:17:20 Brians-mini.local DocKeep[17199] <Error>: CGImageSourceCreateWithURL:  CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -15.
```

anyone know what error -15 is? or where I can find it?

thanks

ETA: I should also mention that I don't have this problem if the path doesn't have spaces in it... (Spaces in filenames are an abomination unto the lord, but I suppose we have to live with them... B-)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `+URLWithString:` for this. Instead use the purpose-built `+fileURLWithPath:`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSString *fullPath =  [[fileNames objectAtIndex:pageNum - 1] string];
CFStringRef fullPathEscaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, 
            (CFStringRef)pdfPath, NULL, NULL,kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, fullPathEscaped, NULL);
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL (url, NULL);
```

Comment: This worked for me, fileURLWithPath: somehow seemed to also encapsulate the application resources path.

Answer (score 0):

Error code -15 is is **kCFURLImproperArgumentsError**.

More info at [Apple documentation for Core Foundation URL Access Utilities Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLAccessUtils/Reference/reference.html).